How can I adjust the indentation settings in Neovim based on file content or a specific keyword?
I'd like to know if it's possible to dynamically adjust indentation settings (e.g., shiftwidth, tabstop, expandtab) based on the content of the file being edited.
For example:

If the file contains a specific keyword or pattern (like # Tab-based formatting in the first few lines), Neovim should switch to tab-based indentation.
Otherwise, it defaults to spaces with a specific shiftwidth and tabstop value.

I know that filetype detection can adjust these settings per file type (which is neat), but I haven't found a way to adjust them dynamically based on file content. Is this achievable with autocmd or Lua scripting in Neovim?
I'd appreciate any insights or examples.

Have you considered using modelines or filetype plugins?

If this is the way it can be done, I guess I'm open to suggestions :)

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

There are several way to control the way Vim indent your buffer.
Modeline
You can instruct Vim to set some of the buffer option in a line of your buffer (usually a comment line).
e.g.:
# vim: et:ts=4:sw=4

More information with :help modeline
Editor Config
You can also create an .editorconfig file in the root of your project to instruct Vim (and other programs) or file should be indented.
.editorconfig:
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
[*.rs]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

Remark: For this method to work with Vim you need to activate a plugin that supports it. For Vim 9.1 you could just activate the builtin editorconfig plugin by adding the following line your vimrc file:
packadd editorconfig

Remark: Neovim supports .editorconfig by default.
Filetype
Provided that the vimrc turn on the custom indentation settings by file type by having the following line in the vimrc file:
filetype plugin indent on

You can send the indentation parameter in the corresponding indentation script.
e.g.: vimfiles/indent/python.vim:
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

The indentation script could be more complex and look at the content of the file:
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
for i in range(3)
  if matchstr(getline(i), 'Tab-based formatting')
    set noexpandtab
  endif
endfor


There is a plugin named vim-sleuth written specifically for this task. Even if you wouldn't like its heuristics you can at least learn by example how it could be done.
But personally I still recommend simply tuning the defaults the way you like most and insert :h modeline whenever you need to make an exception.
